# Change Fragment without change page in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 4 pages. Let's call A, B, C, D.

Pages A, B, C are always the same, but the last page has to show a fragment that depends on the status of the app.
When the user is not logged in, page D has to show the login fragment and when the user is logged in, page D has to show the profile fragment.

To do this, I've simply add a flag to my adapter that controls if the user is logged in or not on page swiping.

The problem is, when the user clicks the login button, I have to show the profile fragment. I cannot force the pager to change the page with a fifth, because I need the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) shows only 4 lines to indicate the pages.

So how can I change the last fragment with another one without change page D?

Keep in mind I cannot use fragment inside fragment technique, because I'm developing for Gingerbread as well.

Comment: *I cannot force the pager to change the page with a fifth, because I need the ViewPagerIndicator shows only 4 lines to indicate the pages.* - You can do this, you just need to make your adapter's `getItem()` method return the new fragment for position 3(and of course call `notifyDataSetChanged()`). *Keep in mind I cannot use fragment inside fragment technique, because I'm developing for Gingerbread as well.* - Yes you can, as the nested fragments are available through the compatibility package.

Answer (score 0):

change your architecture to include fragment pages D, E for ( login aspect, profile aspect ).

Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter so that you can 'remove' viewed pages.

```
 On a stateChange to 'onNoCurrentUser' ...
    ... remove fragment=profile
    ... add fragment=logon 
    ... call notifyDataSetChanged

 On a stateChange to 'onCurrentUser' ...

    ... remove fragment=logon
    ... add fragment=profile
    ... call notifyDataSetChanged
```